# Código en C, pedir 10 números y mostrarlos en pantalla en forma invertida

Tags: c, bucles

mi  código en `C`  solicita por pantalla 10  números cualesquiera para luego mostrarlos en secuencia invertida. El programa en sí está casi completo. Tiene que hacer 2 cosas extras: si se presiona 0 debe mostrar todos los números que se cargaron con anterioridad y cerrarse, eso esta resuelto, y al llegar al final deberá informar todos los números ingresados.

Mi problema ahora es que no muestra los números ingresados y quisiera saber en qué estoy fallando para poder corregirlo y tomar nota de la solución.

El otro detalle es que deben ser mostrados de manera invertida y tampoco se me ocurre algo. ¿tengo que usar la librería `string` para resolver el problema?.

Este es mi programa y muchas gracias por anticipado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  int main(){
    int i=0;
    int numero[11];

while (i<10){
  i++;
  printf("Ingrese un numero(Precione 0 para cerrar): ");
  scanf("%i",&numero[i]);

if (numero[i]==0){
    printf("Los numeros ingresados fueron %i: \n",numero[i]);
   system("pause");
    exit(-1);
}
}
  printf("Limite de numeros ingresados...\n");
  printf("Los numeros ingresados fueron: %i\n",numero[i]);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

PD: Se debe resolver con `while` o `do while` como intento hacerlo.

Comment: De la misma forma en que los agregas puedes ir mostrándonos, es decir en vez de usar un `for` utiliza un `while` para recorrer el array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es interesante abordar tu problema como que primero completes el array completo, y una vez que tengas todos los datos (o se inserte el número '0') comiences a imprimirlos. Por otro lado, ten mucho cuidado con los arrays sin inicializar, ya que si por algún error intentas imprimir una posición del array que no hayas inicializado o asignado un valor, éste te va a imprimir basura.
Una forma de solucionar tu código sería de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0, contador=0;
    int numero[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // Inicializa el array a '0' para el caso en 
                                            // el que el primer numero ingresado sea '0'

    while (i<10) // Insertar valores hasta llenar el array
    {
        i++;
        printf("Ingrese un numero(Precione 0 para cerrar): ");
        scanf("%i",&numero[i]);
        contador++;

        if (numero[i]==0) // Fin de insertar numeros
        {
            contador--;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Limite de numeros ingresados...\n");
    printf("Los numeros ingresados fueron:\n");
    do // Imprime valores en forma invertida
    {
        printf("%i\n",numero[contador]);
        contador--;
    } while (contador>0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Salvo que el usuario introduzca un solo número, siempre vas a mostrar un número menos de los que existan en el array

Comment: Eso y que no has contemplado el caso de que no haya números en el array (es decir, que el primero sea un 0)

Comment: Te compro el caso en el que el primer número sea un 0. En ese caso se imprimirá basura, tal y como he comentado por no inicializar el array (Se puede solucionar inicializando el array `int numero[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`). Por otro lado, cuando te refieres a que "siempre vas a mostrar un número menos de los que existan en el array", te invito a compilar el código y probarlo. Supongo que "compilar" de cabeza a veces falla, ya que el código funciona correctamente e imprime todos y cada uno de los valores dados.

Comment: Sí imprime todos los números introducidos, al contrario de lo que dice @eferion, pero sí es cierto que no hace uso del primer elemento disponible en el buffer, `numero[0]`, porque inicializa `i` con `0` y lo primero que hace en el primer `while` es `i++;`. Por esto es que necesita reservar el buffer con `11` posiciones y luego utilizar `while (i<10)`.

Comment: @V.Lorz no me expliqué bien, imprime todos justamente porque la primera posición no se usa... en cuanto actualices para que se empiece a escribir en el índice 0, el primer elemento desaparecerá como por arte de magia

Comment: Salvo, claro está, que se acrualice el segundo `while` para que itere mientras `contador>=0`

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una pequeña mejora de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/467315/228368) de @[Londo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/231277/londo).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Es preferible evitar el uso de valores "mágicos" en el código.
#define MAX_ELEMS   10

int main()
{
    // No es necesario tener dos contadores. El propio contador de elementos
    // introducidos puede servir en este caso como índice.
    int contador = 0;
    
    // No es necesario inicializar el vector, es suficiente con estructurar
    // el código de manera apropiada.
    int numeros[MAX_ELEMS];

    printf("Ingrese hasta %i valores enteros. El valor 0 finaliza la entrada\n", MAX_ELEMS);
    
    while (contador < MAX_ELEMS)
    {
        printf("\tIngrese un valor: ");
        scanf("%i", &numeros[contador]);

        if (numeros[contador] == 0)
            break;
        contador++;
    }
    
    printf("\nHa ingresado %d valores:\n", contador);
    
    // El valor contador en este momento apunta a la primera localización No
    // utilizada del vector, o a una posición que se encuentra pasada la 
    // localización del último elemento válido del vector. Por eso el --.
    while (contador-- > 0)
    {
        printf("\tValor %i: %i\n",contador, numeros[contador]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Este es el resultado de una ejecución entrando sólo un valor, el 0.

> Ingrese hasta 10 valores enteros. El valor 0 finaliza la entrada
> Ingrese un valor: 0
>
> Ha ingresado 0 valores:
>
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0

Y este es el resultado de una ejecución entrando 10 valores (el programa finaliza automáticamente evitando un *buffer overrun*).

> Ingrese hasta 10 valores enteros. El valor 0 finaliza la entrada
> Ingrese un valor: 1
> Ingrese un valor: 2
> Ingrese un valor: 3
> Ingrese un valor: 4
> Ingrese un valor: 5
> Ingrese un valor: 6
> Ingrese un valor: 7
> Ingrese un valor: 8
> Ingrese un valor: 9
> Ingrese un valor: 10
>
> Ha ingresado 10 valores:
> Valor 9: 10
> Valor 8: 9
> Valor 7: 8
> Valor 6: 7
> Valor 5: 6
> Valor 4: 5
> Valor 3: 4
> Valor 2: 3
> Valor 1: 2
> Valor 0: 1
>
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0